# How to update rows from database using foreach loop?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to loop through all of the orders from Order table, and update each of the order's delivery status when this function is called.

```
public void DateCheck()
        {
            if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Orders", sqlcon);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Orders SET D_Status = @D_Status", sqlcon);
                string deliverytype = row["D_Type"].ToString();
                DateTime orderdate = DateTime.ParseExact(row["O_Date"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                DateTime deliverydate = new DateTime(); 

                if (deliverytype == "Standard") 
                {
                    deliverydate = orderdate.AddDays(7);
                }
                else if (deliverytype == "Express") 
                {
                    deliverydate = orderdate.AddDays(5);
                }
                else if (deliverytype == "One-Day") 
                {
                    deliverydate = orderdate.AddDays(1);
                }

                if (DateTime.Now >= deliverydate)
                {
                    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@D_Status", "Delivered");
                    update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else if (DateTime.Now >= deliverydate)
                {
                    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@D_Status", "Undelivered");
                    update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

However, it updates all of the statuses to "Delivered", even though comparing the code below gives me both "Delivered" and "Undelivered".

```
(DateTime.Now >= deliverydate)
```

Does anyone have any idea where the code goes wrong? If so, kindly elaborate to help me understand my mistake better.

Comment: you have not written any condition in update command..get orderid and add condition to update command

Comment: Your update statement is missing a where clause. This means that it will update every record in the table.

Comment: Just a suggestion - the foreach loop you have posted above can actually be expressed as a single SQL `UPDATE` query, using `CASE ... THEN` for the delivery date

Comment: I see, I thought this would be automatically achieved because I used a foreach loop to loop through all existing orders. However, I'm not sure what conditions I want to put for the UPDATE command? As I just want all of the data within that table to be updated.

Comment: @LeonKho Identify the primary key for Orders table, get that to a variable and in update statement add " where Id = " and pass the variable as parameter..

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan Noted with thanks! Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
DateTime deliveryDate = new DateTime();
```

creates a deliveryDate equals to "01/01/0001 00:00:00", of course adding 7,5 or 1 day doesn't give you a meaningful date to compare against DateTime.Now.

The logic to initialize the deliveryDate variable is not clear but probably you need to initialize it with the orderDate

```
DateTime deliverydate = orderDate;
```

As others say in their comments, an UPDATE command without a WHERE condition updates all records in the table. Again you need some kind of initialization here. Probably, because you use the SELECT * FROM syntax, the record retrieved contains also the primary key of your records, so you can adjust the questy with:

```
string cmdText = "UPDATE Orders SET D_Status = @D_Status WHERE OrderID = @id"
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlcon);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(row["OrderId"]));
.....
```

Comment: That's correct, and duly noted. But the question is: why I get always a status of delivered?

Comment: @steve..so it updates the last row's value(delivered/not delivered) to all rows..

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan no, it updates all records to "Delivered" because the initialization of _deliveryDate_ is wrong. It's not just a matter of fixing the where condition.

Comment: @steve I don't see any problem with deliverydate

Comment: It seems that the foreach doesn't automatically loop through the entire table, so the WHERE condition that you have provided worked! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a where clause with your query. Otherwise it will update all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Following Andrew Williamson's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506623/how-to-update-rows-from-database-using-foreach-loop#comment81969133_47506694) you can use a nested case expression to update all the orders in the table without having any conditions in your c# code at all:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
CREATE TABLE Orders 
(
    O_Id int identity(1,1),
    D_Type varchar(10),
    O_Date datetime,
    D_Status varchar(20)
)
-- Today is 2017-11-27
INSERT INTO Orders (D_Type, O_Date, D_Status) VALUES
('Standard', '2017-12-19T00:00:00', NULL), -- expected result - 'Undelivered'
('Standard', '2017-12-01T00:00:00', NULL), -- expected result - 'Delivered'
('Express', '2017-12-20T00:00:00', NULL), -- expected result - 'Undelivered'
('Express', '2017-11-30T00:00:00', NULL), -- expected result - 'Delivered'
('One-Day', '2017-12-20T00:00:00', NULL), -- expected result - 'Undelivered'
('One-Day', '2017-11-27T00:00:00', NULL) -- expected result - 'Delivered'
```

The update statement:

```
UPDATE Orders 
SET D_Status = CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY
                 , 
                    CASE D_Type 
                    WHEN 'Standard' THEN
                         7
                    WHEN 'Express' THEN
                         5
                    WHEN 'One-Day' THEN
                         1
                    END
                 , GETDATE()) <= O_Date THEN
                    'Delivered'
                ELSE
                    'Undelivered'
                END
```

Test:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
ORDER BY O_Id
```

Results:

```
O_Id    D_Type      O_Date                  D_Status
1       Standard    19.12.2017 00:00:00     Delivered
2       Standard    01.12.2017 00:00:00     Undelivered
3       Express     20.12.2017 00:00:00     Delivered
4       Express     30.11.2017 00:00:00     Undelivered
5       One-Day     20.12.2017 00:00:00     Delivered
6       One-Day     27.11.2017 00:00:00     Undelivered
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/CDDFE15185)

Comment: I apologize for not including a sample table, will take note of this. However, this is just a little project which I don't touch too much on SQL, but more towards C#.

Comment: A smart man once told me that you can chop wood with a hammer, but it's easier to use an axe.